# Trying to compare items in the same column t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I’m trying to find the count of lookupid based on customer

```
LookUpID     Customer
1302                 01             
1303                 01
1337                 01
```

Each customer can have multiple lookupids, but if they have 1337 selected and not 1302 or 1303 than you can’t add that customer to to the count.

Count(case when LookUpID=1337 and LookUpID not in (1302,1303) then 0 
when LookUpID = 1337 and LookUpID in (1302,1303) then 1 else 0 end)

I can’t find out how to exclude customers with LookUpID = 1337 if the other 2 aren’t selected. Any input would help, thanks.

Comment: Can we assume the selected records are in another table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the selected records are in the `SelectedRecords` table, we can do this:

```
SELECT lt.Customer
FROM LookupTable lt
LEFT JOIN SelectedRecords sr ON sr.LookUpID=lt.LookUpID
GROUP BY lt.Customer
HAVING COUNT(*)=COUNT(DISTINCT sr.LookUpID)
```

This way, we are counting the number of LookUpID-s of each customer and checking if the number of selected LookUpID-s is the same.

Comment: @quinnf: please mark which answers are helpful and which have solved your problem, or comment what's wrong with each answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some variant of this:

```
SELECT [Customer]
      ,CASE WHEN MAX([LookUpID]) = 1337 AND  MIN([LookUpID]) = 1337 THEN 0 ELSE COUNT([LookUpID]) END
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY [Customer];
```

If the `min` and the `max` value for particular record are both `1337`, the we have only one record for the row and we have `count = 0`; in all other case, just count.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you.
If you need to count customer then use count over t.customer

```
CREATE TABLE #test(
[lookupid] [int] NULL,
[customer] [varchar](2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT #test ([lookupid], [customer]) VALUES (1302, N'01')
INSERT #test ([lookupid], [customer]) VALUES (1303, N'01')
INSERT #test ([lookupid], [customer]) VALUES (1337, N'01')
INSERT #test ([lookupid], [customer]) VALUES (1337, N'02')
INSERT #test ([lookupid], [customer]) VALUES (1337, N'03')
INSERT #test ([lookupid], [customer]) VALUES (1303, N'03')

-- select *   from #test

 select r.customer,t.customer,r.lookupid
  from #test r
  left join (select * from #test where lookupid=1337  
            and customer in(select customer from  #test
            where lookupid in(1302,1303)))t on t.customer=r.customer
```